# Why google don't recommend using supervisord for container? Does supervisord handle PID 1 problem well while running in kubernetes?

Tags: python, linux, docker, kubernetes, supervisord

According to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-for-building-containers), Google mentioned

> You might see the following actions in public images, but do not
> follow their example:
>
> - Using a process management system such as supervisord to manage one or
>   several apps in the container.

I understand there's many downside of using supervisord to manage multiple app in one container. Such as not ideal for autoscaling, hard to health check etc..
But is there any other downside of it? I wonder how supervisord handle PID 1 problem?

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of reasons but a few of them are:

- Docker is designed to keep applications as separated containers.
- It is easier to control application if you have single application in single container
- Docker has mechanism called health-check which monitor your application health. You lose it totally when you use supervisord, because you SHOULD NOT monitor 2 applications at the same time.
- Monitoring single application is easier. When you have 2 applications in container and your container is using too much resources, you do not know which is broken.
- Scaling container is easier when you have single application. You can scale single application
- When you have single application for example Nginx, you can reuse it for multiple projects.
- Logging is easier when only single application is logging to stdout/stderr
- Networking and security is easier when your applications are split.
- Docker has its own process manager.

Some of them are personal but you can see this is bad practice to use multiple apps in container.

## More technical things

- You should have only one parent process. Docker can send singnal only to process PID1. If you have multiple top level processes, one process cannot gracefully exit.
- Most of init systems kill the orphaned processes. So If you have 2 processes started as background process in the entrypoint it will be killed.

Comment: I've edit my question a little bit. Actually I'm more curious about how supervisord handle PID 1 problem mentioned in [google post](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-for-building-containers)

Answer (score 2):

Both supervisord and Docker are process managers and they both can do log forwarding, restart crashed workers. If you run supervisord inside of a docker container you will face issues with your service:

- If you will run a single process per container with supervisord you will not gain much except for increased memory consumption.
- To restart the process you have only restart the docker container
- Running multiple process might creat issue of monitoring
- Health checks requests for a single supervisord process will be distributed across workers which is likely to hide unhealthy targets
- Worker crashes are hidden will be hard to get idea about it using anytype of monitoring
- Load balancing will be harder as will have multiple levels of load balancing
- You can go with the supervisord or pm2 when you have limited control over the docker environment.